# Use TabNavigator as a button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) and I want to use TabNavigator to navigate through multiple tabs. What I don't know is if there is a possibility to use one tab as a button.

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Tab1: { screen: Tab1 },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2 },
    Button: {//This needs to be a button },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
    Tab4: { screen: Tab4 },   
}, 
{
  //some TabBarOptions
}
```

I have tried to exclude the screen prop in Button and wrap it in `<Touchable>`, but I get the error that screen needs to be defined.

```
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|Tab 1|Tab 2| But |Tab 3|Tab 4|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Comment: what are you intend to do with the button tab page? An entire page with a button?

Comment: @KimHau No, I want to open a menu on button press.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a tab just as a button by setting the tabs in the **tabBarComponent** property.

**This is an example from the native-base( [ui library for react native](http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/navigation/StackNavigationExample.html) ) docs :** 
Native base

You can just modify the `onPress()` method of the button to do what you'd like

```
export default (MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    LucyChat: { screen: LucyChat },
    JadeChat: { screen: JadeChat },
    NineChat: { screen: NineChat }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarComponent: props => {
      return (
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
           <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 0}
              onPress={() => alert("Do something")}> //this is the change
              <Icon name="bowtie" />
              <Text>Button</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 1}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("LucyChat")}>
              <Icon name="bowtie" />
              <Text>Lucy</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 2}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("JadeChat")}>
              <Icon name="briefcase" />
              <Text>Nine</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 3}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("NineChat")}>
              <Icon name="headset" />
              <Text>Jade</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      );
    }
  }
));
```